# What shape would an explosion be in orbit?

Tags: gravity

In the Gravity movie discussions we learn that objects accellerated towards an object in the same orbit miss it and move to a higher orbit. Objects accellerated away from an object in the same orbit move to a lower orbit.
What shape would an explosion be in orbit?

Edit. Compared to an explosion in space that is not in an orbit. How would the shape of the trajectories of shrapnel evolve over distance and time.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're talking about milliseconds/seconds after the explosion, or hours, or days. If it's milliseconds the effects of gravity are pretty unimportant, and the primary difference between space/earth will be atmospheric pressure, the presence/lack of solid ground, and the presence/lack of oxidizer in the atmosphere.

Answer (score 2):

In orbit, the shape of an explosion would be governed by the nature of the explosion itself and not particularly governed by gravity, just as it is here on the planet's surface.  I'm sure you can imagine the difference between an explosion on a flat field versus one that is just in front of a barrier.  The same forces would work in space, with gravity significantly affecting the longer term trajectory, such as the orbit, but not the shape of the explosion itself.

Comment: I'm assuming a spherical explosion  would look different in orbit because no shrapnel accelerated along the orbit line could stay on that line so there would have to be two wedge shaped gaps in what would normally be a sphere?

Comment: @Jitter Er...no. There is nothing magical about straight ahead or straight back. To first order all effects are simply tidal in nature and are continuous.

Comment: Remember gravity is a force.  In orbit around earth, the force is small (which is why astronauts in the International Space Station float around weightlessly).  In your "spherical explosion" the cause of the explosion is another much larger force.  Since forces on individual objects are additive and because the word "explosion" implies considerable force (because the shrapnel bits accelerate rapidly), the larger force added to a very tiny force is approximately the same as just the larger force.  In other words, in orbit, gravity doesn't contribute much.

Comment: *"the force is small (which is why astronauts in the International Space Station float around weightlessly)"* This is an incorrect explanation. The astronauts float around in the can because they and the can are *both* falling under the influence of the same gravitational acceleration.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and thanks for your correction.  What I should have said is that the force of gravity on the individual shrapnel pieces is the same both before and after the explosion.